# MySQL - Select result where field is empty or doesn't exists

Tags: mysql, database, select, where-clause

I've got a MySQL table with movies and flexible data. Not every movie has the same fields (filled).

However I want to do a query that finds all movies where a specific field is empty or doesn't exist.

This is an example of what my database table looks like:

```
| id | article_id | fieldname | content          |
|----|------------|-----------|------------------|
| 1  | 1          | title     | Star Wars        |
| 2  | 1          | director  | George Lucas     |
| 3  | 1          | actor     | Harrison Ford    |
|----|------------|-----------|------------------|
| 4  | 2          | title     | Jurassic Park    |
| 5  | 2          | duration  | Jeff Goldblum    |
|----|------------|-----------|------------------|
| 6  | 3          | title     | E.T.             |
| 7  | 3          | actor     |                  |
| 8  | 3          | director  | Steven Spielberg |
```

How can I get all movies where "actor" is empty or doesn't exist?

Comment: Do you have a table that lists all possible values of `fieldname`?

Comment: Yes, I know what values could be in "fieldname".

Comment: Then `LEFT JOIN` your FieldName table to your main table and then `IS NULL` will pint to "missing" entries.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE content IS NULL AND fieldname = 'actor'
```

should do the trick.